# stereoEffect and CSS3DStereoEffect threejs

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm making a VR application. So far I've done the desktop version. For mobiles devices I plan to use google cardboard with a stereoEffect, but I'm using a cssRenderer and a webglRenderer together.

My question is how do I use stereoEffect and CSS3DStereoEffect together?

Here's an inline link to my [demo app](http://oikoscrm.com/threejs/demo/).

Comment: I have made the english a little more readable.

Comment: Also, you need to explain more about what you have tried, what you have researched on the internet, what is going wrong, errors, etc.